# Is it possible to auto-dial in background on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

Is it possible to make calls programmatically in background on iOS? I have been using this code to make calls in my app:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://"stringByAppendingString:mymobileNO.titleLabel.text];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phone calls are handled by the Phone app which is assigned the URL Scheme of `tel://`. You can't call a number and stay in your own app using just iOS libraries.

What you can do is implement a third-party VoIP solution such as [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/client/mobile).